# how to properly get recordlist working with the conatct class using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a **contact** class below which works fine.

Now I want to add a function called **Recordlist** to the contact class.  When I pass the function to **componentDidMount()** function as per below
nothing is showned. if i pass the function directly under the contact class, it will throw error unexpected token.

```
componentDidMount(){
    function RecordList() {
        const userid = 101;
        const username = 'henry';
        alert(username);

        return (
            <ul>
                <b>Hey {username} the function is working</b>
            </ul>
        );
    }
}
```

please how do add and display the content of this function to or within contact class. any work around will be appreciated

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class Contact extends React.Component{
//class Contact extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: ''
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
             <h2>Hello welcome to contact page</h2>
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

Comment: What you want to do?

Comment: Why you're defining function in componentDidMount?

Comment: @Abhay Sehgal thanks for responding. I want to render or show the result or content of the function eg `<ul>
            <b>Hey {username} the function is working</b>
         </ul>`

Comment: any work around will be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';


class Contact extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            id: ''
        };
    }

    RecordList() {
        const userid = 101;
        const username = 'henry';

        return (
          <ul>
            <b>Hey {username} the function is working</b>
          </ul>
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
             <h2>Hello welcome to contact page</h2>
             {this.RecordList()}
          </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Contact;
```

Comment: I wrote the working code above. But if you are going to declare component, try to declare another component. And also in componentDidMount, any function declaration won't work. So you need to declare outside of componentDidMount() and just call like this.functionName(). Hope this helps you to understand!